# Second intent in onClick is executed before first

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, android-gallery

I am writing an Android application and faced the problem:
I need to choose an image from the gallery and then send it to the other activity (and go to that activity). When I only have an Intent which picks an image from gallery, it's doing fine, opens the gallery, lets you pick an image and then nothing happens, fine. 
But when I add another Intent which goes to other activity, it ignores the first intent.

```
ImageButton gallery;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gallery = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

                goToConfirmActivity();
            }
        });
    }
    public void goToConfirmActivity(){
        Intent goToConfirmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, confirmActivity.class);
        goToConfirmIntent.putExtra("image", uri);
        startActivity(goToConfirmIntent);
    }
```

It just goes straight to `confirmActivity` without choosing a pic from the gallery. I wonder how to fix that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Override onActivityResult and then call goToConfirmActivity () after you get the image uri from result

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `goToConfirmActivity();` immediately after launching the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Since the call to get content is asynchronous, control will continue to execute next line. As a result `goToConfirmActivity();` will be executed and next intent will be launched. To avoid this override `onActivityResult` as follows

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
        //You can get URI from intent data
        goToConfirmActivity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override onActivityResult, as then you can check whether a user actually picked an image from gallery or just pressed back button after opening the gallery.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri= data.getData();
        goToConfirmActivity(uri);
    } else {
        //Some error has occurred.
    }
}
```

And your goToConfirmActivity method should be like:

```
void goToConfirmActivity(Uri uri){
    Intent goToConfirmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, confirmActivity.class);
    goToConfirmIntent.putExtra("image", uri);
    startActivity(goToConfirmIntent);
}
```